# Is it possible to do screen recording on AWS workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, compliance

I've been used to using tools like observit and cyberark psm for screen recording.  Moving to a more distributed cloud-based toolset and want to keep the same level of compilance, is there a way to do screen recording of AWS workspace instances.  The 'monitoring' in AWS docs is just talking about cloudwatch metrics and stuff, but that wouldn't satisfy the level of compliance I need.

Is there a simple way to use native AWS tools to record activities on workstations deployed in AWS?

Comment: I haven't heard of any AWS specific way to do screen recording. Most standard windows tools work on Workspaces. Spin one up and give it a try, it might cost you $10 to test this out due to the monthly component of the fees - though Workspaces is available on the free tier https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-workspaces-now-offers-free-tier-for-new-customers/